# iOS iCloud: Deleting data doesnt work

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I currently implement iCloud core data syncing in my ios app.
The data sync works fine but there is a problem.
I have pre filled data that every time will be synced with iCloud when the app launches the first time. The result are duplicates :-(

Is there a smart solution for that issue?
I know that iCloud doesn't care about duplicates, but maybe somebody got an idea or workaround.

I can't find anything useful in the web for that issue...

regards

Comment: You'll have to post some sample code, the only time I've used iCloud data syncing is with UserDefaults.

Comment: Apple's **SharedCoreData** demo code from WWDC 2012 included a decent example of detecting and removing duplicates.